# Laravel deployed site only works with IP, error 419 page expired with domain

Tags: laravel, apache, dns, ip

I have recently deployed my first Laravel project to a server. After setup up the server using Apache, configuring my DNS i'm having the issue that it only works if I use the server IP address. Through the domain when I try to login I get a 419 'page expired'. Again everything works perfectly though IP. I feel it's something related to the handle of the session in Laravel. I have already tried setting the SESSION DOMAIN in the .en file. Any ideas or suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: I didn't faced that issue but you can change the session_driver to file in .env file and check it

Comment: When you access the site via the DNS open the developer tools of the browser and check the request/response and specifically the cookies. Try and find anything that looks out of the ordinary (make sure you include all cookies that are sent by the server)